# What are clang's compiled module pcm files for?

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, c++-modules

I'm looking at the driver test cases for clang modules:
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/test/Driver/modules.cpp

It includes steps to produce .pcm.o files. I'm wondering what they are for.

Given a c++20 module

```
// a-m.cc
module;
#include <iostream>
export module a;
export void do_a() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
```

You can compile it using

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -x c++-module --precompile a-m.cc -o a.pcm
```

which produces the precompiled module file `a.pcm`.

But there are also steps to compile .pcm files to .o files.

From the driver [tests](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/test/Driver/modules.cpp#L13-L15):

```
clang++ -std=c++20 a.pcm -S -o a.pcm.o
```

How are the .pcm.o files meant to be used?

If I write a main program

```
// main.cc
import a;

int main() {
    do_a();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -c main.cc -fmodule-file=a=a.pcm
```

And then try to link with the .pcm.o, I get

```
clang++ main.o a.pcm.o
/usr/bin/ld:a.pcm.o: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:a.pcm.o:2: syntax error
clang-13: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note: you can compile a-m.cc

```
clang++ std=c++20 -c a-m.cc -o a.o
```

and link with a.o, but what are the .pcm.o files for? and can they be used to avoid compiling a-m.cc again after you've precompiled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pcm-files contains "half baked" information about a module. The file extension does not have to be pcm and i think Visual Studio for example uses `.ifc` as extension. (And a difference with Visual Studio is that it outputs the ifc-file and compiles the object file (`.obj`) at the same time, while clang does this in two separate steps)

The pcm file is storing the information about the module file in a format so that the compiler can easily import it or compile it to other object files.

The command from your link surprises me, I think that `-S` in the example is compiling to assembly, so i am surprised that it is listed in that clang repo that you linked to.

```sh
clang++ -std=c++20 a.pcm -S -o a.pcm.o # To mee this looks wrong (assembly output)
```

Try changing it to use `-c` instead

```sh
clang++ -std=c++20 a.pcm -c -o a.pcm.o # This is how you compile pcm-files to object files
```

Comment: has clang or cmake changed anything related to modules recently to ease using it?

Comment: @asmmo not that I know of, In some years when build system has started supporting modules I do not think that will that much of a problem though.

Comment: It's not very hard to support moduels with custom rules in bazel: see https://github.com/rnburn/rules_cc_module. But compiler support is so buggy, modules aren't really usable (at least for gcc and clang). See, for example, [99569](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99569) and [99568](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99568))

Comment: You're right about it producing assembly; though even after removing the "-S" option I still wasn't able to produce a linkable object from the pcm.